# Null pointer Exception in facebook login with android app in loginTofacebook() method

Tags: android

this is my code and getting null pointer exception when i click login button Please help me to run my app

when I run my app ot gives unnfortunatrly app stoped

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button login;
     public static Facebook facebook = null;
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = null;
     String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
     private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
     String _error;
     ArrayList<String> friends_list;
     ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

    }

    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        loginToFacebook();
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {
         mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

         if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
             facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                     new DialogListener() {

                         public void onCancel() {
                             // Function to handle cancel event
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                             // Function to handle complete event
                             // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                             editor.putString("access_token",
                                     facebook.getAccessToken());
                             editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                     facebook.getAccessExpires());
                             editor.commit();     

                         mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                             login.setText("LogOut");

                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onError(DialogError error) {
                             // Function to handle error

                         }

                         public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                             // Function to handle Facebook errors

                         }

                     });
         }
     }
```

Comment: when you post here and you have error then always try to put logcat here.

Comment: facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID); initialize facebook

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
in.example.facebookfriendlist.MainActivity.loginToFacebook(MainActivity.java:80)
in.seriapin.facebookfriendlist.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:876)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loginToFacebook()
        {
            if (CheckInternet(getApplicationContext()))
                {
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

                    // if session is in exceptional state
                    if (session.getState() == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED || session.getState() == SessionState.OPENING)
                        {
                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        }

                    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed())
                        {
                            String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ =
                                { "email", "user_birthday" };
                            List<String> PERMISSION_LIST = Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);
                            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(UserRegistration.this).setPermissions(PERMISSION_LIST).setCallback(
                                    statusCallback));
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            Session.openActiveSession(UserRegistration.this, true, statusCallback);
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connection is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
```

this code works fine for me.